# What is the origin of "brake" in "press brake"?

Tags: etymology

> A **[press brake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Press_brake)** is a machine tool for bending sheet and plate material, most commonly sheet metal.

But why is it called **brake**? Why not **press sheet bender**? How did it come to be called **brake**?

I looked up **brake** in the Etymology Dictionary, but its explanation does not seem to cover the "bending" sense of the word:

> [image: Screenshot of definition of brake]

[image: Animation of press brake machine]

Comment: You can clearly see the _crushing_ action of the press brake in the animation!

Comment: @P.E.Dant - ah, I never thought of that. I imagined "crushing" as "crushing something to small bits and pieces".

Comment: Nice animated .gif, by the way. I can't imagine how you found an animated press brake!

Comment: I don't see much similarity between a modern brake for a wheel and any of the old definitions of brake. I guess a bicycle or motorcycle brake includes the little arm that you pull to activate it.

Comment: One of the slickest off-topic questions ever asked here on ELL. Etymological picnics summon the harpies  :)   Better ask over on ELU.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The [help center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has been updated to reflect that etymology is not explicitly off-topic on ELL because it was causing too many harpy flocks ;) (Well, and there is an argument that etymology is a very relevant and useful topic for folks learning English).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In anticipation of a transfer by the mods over to ELU...

My suggestion would be that this use of **brake** comes from a particular meaning of the verb **break** (ME **breken**), namely, to bend, to change direction, to deflect, rather than the core meaning of 'to split asunder, to breach'.

[In the 15th c](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=20563290&egdisplay=open&egs=20659550). we could *break* (turn) eastward, and we could *break* (draw back) the string of a bow (to shoot an arrow), or *break* (deflect) a beam of light.

see MED, **breken**, #22.

Comment: Very interesting information about the verb's 15th-century usage. This is what I was trying to find out, in order to better remember this term, by making it more logical.